# Linux raw datalink layer socket only returns partial packet (96 bytes)

Tags: linux, sockets

In my application, I am receiving packets at the data link layer using a raw socket `(type PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)`.  What I am finding is that I only get the first 96 bytes of any packet.  I'm assuming there is some option somewhere that is preventing me from receiving the entire packet, but what?
Here is a snipped from my code:

```
int sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
int nBytesRead = read(sock, (char *) buf, 1500);
int nFlags = fcntl(m_sock, F_GETFL, 0);     // make it non-blocking
fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, nFlags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

nBytesRead is never more than 96, even though my network sniffer shows longer packets.  This is uClinux if that makes a difference.
I found someone else with the same problem at http://www.network-builders.com/raw-socket-captures-only-first-96-bytes-packet-t57283.html but no answers there.

Comment: Post the full source code of your example application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!  What I failed to mention in my original post was that I was attaching a filter to the raw socket so it would only receive traffic on certain TCP/IP ports.  This filter code was created with TCPDUMP, which apprently limits capture to 96 bytes by default.  I had to add the `-s0` option to my TCPDUMP command line to tell it to capture everything:
`tcpdump -dd -s0 "ip and tcp and dst port 60001"`.

With that change, it now gives me the full packet.  Thanks to [this blog post](http://quimicefa.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/tcpdump-%E2%80%93-packet-size-limited-during-capture-eng/) for the clue.
Hope this helps someone else in the future.